# Properly setting up willSelectRowAtIndexPath and didSelectRowAtIndexPath to send cell selections

Tags: iphone, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

Feel like I'm going a bit nutty here. I have a detail view with a few stand-alone `UITextField`s, a few `UITextFields` in `UITAbleViewCell`s, and one single `UITableViewCell` that will be used to hold notes, if there are any. I only want this cell selectable when I am in edit mode. When I am not in edit mode, I do not want to be able to select it. Selecting the cell (while in edit mode) will fire a method that will init a new view. I know this is very easy, but I am missing something somewhere.

Here are the current selection methods I am using:

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!self.editing) {
        NSLog(@"Returning nil, not in edit mode");
        return nil;
    }
    NSLog(@"Cell will be selected, not in edit mode");
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Comments cell will be selected");
        return indexPath;
    }
    return nil;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!self.editing) {
        NSLog(@"Not in edit mode. Should not have made it this far.");
        return;
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
        [self pushCommentsView];
    else
        return;
}
```

My problem is really 2 fold;

1) Even when I'm not in edit mode, and I know I am returning `nil` (due to the `NSLog` message), I can still select the row (it flashes blue). From my understanding of the `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, this shouldn't be happening. Maybe I am wrong about this?

2) When I enter edit mode, I can't select anything at all. the `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` method never fires, and neither does the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. The only thing I am doing in the `setEditing` method, is hiding the back button while editing, and assigning `firstResponder` to the top textField to get the keyboard to pop up.  I thought maybe the first responder was getting in the way of the click (which would be dumb), but even with that commented out, I cannot perform the cell selection during editing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Good lord I am an idiot. I never added these lines:

```
self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO; // Keeps cells from being selectable while not editing. No more blue flash.
self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES; // Allows cells to be selectable during edit mode.
```

Sorry for the garbage question.

Comment: In Xcode 4.2/iOS5, these can be set on the TableView in Interface Builder.

Comment: Solved it by choosing `Single Selection` in the Storyboard/Interface Builder's "selection" option. THANKS!

Answer (score 4):

The documentation notes that `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` isn't called when in editing mode. In addition, the blue flash will happen even if you cancel the selection. From the documentation:

> This method is not called until users touch a row and then lift their finger; the row isn't selected until then, although it is highlighted on touch-down. You can use UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone to disable the appearance of the cell highlight on touch-down. This method isn’t called when the editing property of the table is set to YES (that is, the table view is in editing mode).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Got me to double check the docs, which made me realize my dumb mistake.

Comment: Just want to clarify this answer by quoting the documentation in full: "...This method isn’t called when the table view is in editing mode (that is, the editing property of the table view is set to YES) **unless the table view allows selection during editing (that is, the allowsSelectionDuringEditing property of the table view is set to YES).**"